# Extrair dados array JSON no Android recebidos por DataSnap

Tags: java, android, json, delphi, datasnap

Boa tarde. Gostaria de saber como posso extrair os dados recebidos pelo servidor, utilizando o DataSnap do Delphi. Estou fazendo da seguinte forma, porém está retornando um erro:

```
lista_versoes = dsProxy.getVersoes();

TJSONObject json_versao = new TJSONObject();
      for (int i=0; i < lista_versoes.size(); i++){
           json_versao = lista_versoes.getAsJsonObject(i);
           String versao = json_versao.getString("FVersao");
       }
```

A variável lista_versoes recebe este valor a partir do dsProxy.getVersoes():

```
["{\"type\":\"ClassesProjeto.TVersao\",\"id\":1,\"fields\":{\"FVersao\":1,\"FData_inc\":42230,\"FHora_inc\":0.904861111111111}}"]
```

Erro:

> java.lang.ClassCastException: com.embarcadero.javaandroid.TJSONString cannot be cast to com.embarcadero.javaandroid.TJSONObject
>               at com.embarcadero.javaandroid.TJSONArray.getJSONObject(TJSONArray.java:220)
>               at com.nutricionista.tela.TelaLogin$4.run(TelaLogin.java:205)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Não precisa utilizar gson não. Se preferir vc pode usar assim:

```
TJSONObject objJSON = (TJSONObject) mrUsuario.Get(IdUsuario);

TJSONObject objFIELDS = objJSON.getJSONObject("fields");
int varinteger = objFIELDS.getInt("FID");
String aux = objFIELDS.getString("FNome");
//FNome = é conforme vem no teu JSON no caso ai eu fiz um Get no meu modulo remoto q me retorno meu objeto TUsuario.
```

Answer (score 1):

Talvez você possa utiliza a biblioteca GSON do Google (https://code.google.com/p/google-gson/) e transformar a String em um objeto Java, por exemplo:

```
String strJson = "{\"name\":\"Fulano\"}";
Gson gson = new Gson();
Person person = gson.fromJson(strJson, Person.class);
System.out.println(person.getName());
```

Nesse caso, foi criada uma classe Java Person com o seguinte código:

```
public class Person {

    private String name;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```